Add and rotate text 45 degrees PIL/Pillow
I tried adding text and rotating it
I need to rotate the text 45 degrees, but Image.ROTATE_90 does not exist
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.open("good_watermark.jpg")

width, height = image.size
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 25)
font = ImageFont.TransposedFont(font, orientation=Image.ROTATE_90)

drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
drawer.text((height/2, width/3), "@channel", font=font, fill='black')

image.save('new_img.jpg')
image.show()

I was trying to create a separate image with a transparent background and text and add it to the main image. But for some reason the text does not appear
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

background_image = Image.open("white_img.jpeg")
width, height = background_image.size

text_image = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_image)

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 40)
draw.text((height/2, width/3), "TEXT", font=font)

rotated_text_image = text_image.rotate(45)
background_image.paste(rotated_text_image, (0, 0), mask=rotated_text_image)

background_image.save("new_img.jpg")

I also tried to use the solution from here
How do I draw text at an angle using python's PIL?
Pillow, add and rotate text in a image
I tried a lot of things but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I will be glad to any answer

The code first creates a transparent image with the text "TEXT" drawn in black at its center. Then, it rotates this text image by 45 degrees, filling the newly transparent areas with white to avoid visual artifacts. Finally, the rotated text image is pasted onto the center of the background image, maintaining transparency and achieving a centered, rotated text effect.
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

background_image = Image.open("white.jpg")
width, height = background_image.size

text_image = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0)) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_image)

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 40)

text_width = draw.textlength("TEXT", font=font)
text_height = font.size  

x = (width - text_width) / 2 - text_width * 0.05 
y = (height - text_height) / 2                  
# Draw text before rotation
draw.text((x, y), "TEXT", font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0, 255))  

rotated_text_image = text_image.rotate(45, expand=True, fillcolor="white") 

rot_width, rot_height = rotated_text_image.size
center_x = (width - rot_width) // 2
center_y = (height - rot_height) // 2

background_image.paste(rotated_text_image, (center_x, center_y), mask=rotated_text_image)


background_image.save("new_img.jpg")

Output is like:


from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

text = '@estate_bot'
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 30)

image1 = Image.open('good_watermark.jpg')
draw1 = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)
width, height = image1.size

image2 = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw2 = ImageDraw.Draw(image2)
draw2.text((height/2, width/3), text=text, font=font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 150))  
# (255, 255, 255, 150) 4th parameter - transparency

image2 = image2.rotate(38)

px, py = 10, 10
sx, sy = image2.size
image1.paste(im=image2, box=(px, py, px + sx, py + sy), mask=image2)

image1.save('new_img.jpg', quality=100)
image1.show()

